# Which wire do I attach to what when installing a light fixture?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm trying to change a light fixture for the first time and I don't know which wires to attach to which. Here's images explaining:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### One hot yellow wire

Your wiring is likely in conduit, hence the yellow hot wire.  Turn the circuit off at the breaker, then connect yellow to both blacks, white to both whites, and green to the bare ground.  Button things back up, turn the breaker back on, and enjoy your new light fixture!

Comment: Thank you! With your help, I just installed my first light fixture!

Comment: In the future, how am I able to tell which is what? Is there some kind of instrument that'll tell me?

Comment: @Jessica -- a non-contact voltage tester is probably the simplest and cheapest thing to have that'll help you out with such work (although it can get confused in more complicated situations) -- I consider it an essential for anyone who wants to work on household wiring